# AngularJs - ng-options object.object

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-options

I am displaying countries and cities in a select box in angularjs, which are working fine. ng-model of country displays the output when I call {{country}}. However ng-model of city couldn't be called as {{city}} with its modal name. I want to call it as {{city}} rather than {{city.city}}. Note, both select boxes are working fine except the modal of city, which couldn't be displayed {{city}}

Otherwise, can I obtain city results when I select country through ng-repeat rather than ng-options

```
<select name="Country" ng-model="country" class="item item-input item-select major" required>
                                    <option value=""> Select a Country  </option>
                                    <option ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country.iso_code_3}}">{{country.name}}</option>
                                </select>


    <select name="City" ng-model="city" data-ng-options="city.name for city in cities| filter:{CountryCode: country}:true" class="item item-input item-select major" required>
                                    <option value="">-- Select a City --</option>
                                </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click this [**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/7may3zkF47rISPOmQNe9?p=preview) example

**Html Code** for reference:

```
 <html ng-app="myapp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.5.x"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select ng-model="country" data-ng-options="country for country in countries" ng-change="countryChange()">
      <option value="">Select country</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <select ng-model="state" ng-options="state for state in allStates">
      <option value="">Select state</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Country: {{country}}
    <br>
    State: {{state}}
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS code** for reference:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.countries = ["USA","Canada"];
    $scope.states = [{
        "name": "Alabama",
        "countryId": "USA"
      }, {
        "name": "Alaska",
        "countryId": "USA"
      }, {
        "name": "Arizona",
        "countryId": "USA"
      }, {
        "name": "Alberta",
        "countryId": "Canada"
      }, {
        "name": "British columbia",
        "countryId": "Canada"
    }];

    $scope.countryChange = function(){
      $scope.allStates = [];
      angular.forEach($scope.states, function(value){
        if($scope.country == value.countryId){
          $scope.allStates.push(value.name);
        }
      });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/mQvoxoSdFNTvkQxqt53n?p=preview) fro dependable country state drop-down list box

alter your **HTML code**  below

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="CountriesController">
    <select ng-model="country" data-ng-options="country.name for country in countries" ng-change="updateCountry()">
      <option value="">Select country</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <select ng-model="state" ng-options="state.name for state in availableStates">
      <option value="">Select state</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Selected Country: {{country}}
    <br>
    Selected State: {{state}}
  </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

function CountriesController($scope) {
    $scope.countries = [{
        "name": "USA",
        "id": 1
      },{
        "name": "Canada",
        "id": 2
    }];
    $scope.states = [{
        "name": "Alabama",
        "id": 1,
        "countryId": 1
      }, {
        "name": "Alaska",
        "id": 2,
        "countryId": 1
      }, {
        "name": "Arizona",
        "id": 3,
        "countryId": 1
      }, {
        "name": "Alberta",
        "id": 4,
        "countryId": 2
      }, {
        "name": "British columbia",
        "id": 5,
        "countryId": 2
    }];

    $scope.updateCountry = function(){
      $scope.availableStates = [];

      angular.forEach($scope.states, function(value){
        if(value.countryId == $scope.country.id){
          $scope.availableStates.push(value);
        }
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is fine thanks, however you should call  {{country.name}} to display country name. I want to just call country in the ng-modal and then I can use $scope.country in my controller. How to do that?